# How can I prevent the "... has stopped working" window on my Server 2008 R2 dev box?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm using a Windows Server 2008 x64 R2 machine as a development box.  Amongst many other things I've got Visual Studio 2008 SP1 installed on it.  When I'm working on a project, I sometimes need to use Debug > Start without Debugging (Ctrl + F5).  If the program throws an exception, I get a new R2-style window appear.  I'm pretty sure I didn't see this on my XP box - this is the first time I've developed directly on a server.  Is there any way to avoid this - it's really beginning to bug me?

E.g. my current project is accessing a WCF service - I'm using Ctrl+F5 to start a console program client.  I run it and get the window.  The title is the name of the project I've just started and it contains:

```
[insert-project-name-here] has stopped working

Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.

--> Check online for a solution and close the program

--> Close the program

--> Debug the program

V  View problem details.
```

Clicking on "Close the program" will actually close the window and the exception message appears in the console, which is what I want (but without the extra window-faffing).

How can I avoid this annoyance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Just-In-Time Debugging on Windows Vista and 2008 Server**
>
> By default on Windows Vista, the
>   just-in-time debugger is configured to
>   display a user-friendly dialog shown
>   below. Although you can click the
>   Debug the program button and start the
>   debugger successfully, your original
>   Visual Studio instance will hang in
>   the end of the debugging session.
>
> In order to avoid having to constantly
>   kill the Visual Studio process after
>   debugging, you will want to change
>   Just-In-Time debugger configuration to
>   work the same way it does on Windows
>   XP and Windows Server 2003. This
>   configuration is stored in registry as
>   DbgJITDebugLaunchSetting value in
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework
>   key. It’s default value on Windows
>   Vista is 0×10. Change it to 0×2, which
>   is the default value on Windows XP.
>   After making this change, you should
>   no longer see the User-Defined
>   Breakpoint dialog and will be able to
>   continue using Visual Studio after
>   debugging.

from [this page](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-debugging-code-generation-files/) and scroll down to 'Just-In-Time Debugging on Windows Vista and 2008 Server'

Also note: if you are running x64 the key is going to be in the WOW section.

Comment: Thanks for that and, in particular, for the reminder about WOW. +1 for that.

Answer (score 6):

Those answers did not fix my Windows 7 x64 - even after a reboot, but this did:
http://www.mattsilverman.com/2011/04/windows-is-checking-for-a-solution-to-the-problem.html

From the start menu, type: "Choose how to report problem"

then in the window that pops up select "Never check for solutions"

Answer (score 3):

Or you can try this:

1. Click start and type gpedit.msc on search bar or on RUN command
2. Now navigate to
   Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Internet Communication Management, and then click Internet Communication settings
3. Locate Turn off Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program , double click or right click edit.
4. Click on Enable . Apply and Ok and close gpedit window.

(credits go to http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7files/thread/291c0945-c41f-4c8b-bca1-6b6d0836f62a)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Server 2008, this should do it:

```
serverWerOptin /disable
```

You'll need to run cmd.exe as Administrator to make it work.  You might also need to run the "Never check for solutions" and "Turn off Windows Customer Experience Improvement Program" steps from this thread.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me.  Instead:

I went into the Group Policy Editor by clicking Start and typing gpedit.msc on search bar.

Then I enabled Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Error Reporting > Prevent display of the user interface for critical errors”