# Avoid cmd stuck on sub command crashes

Tags: windows, cmd, crash

I have a command that i want to run until its successful.

```
:repeat
<my_command.exe> || goto :repeat
echo Success!
```

I keep this running overnight.
When i come back next day, i find that first run of `my_command.exe` has crashed and is blocking next run as it has opened a modal box with text : `Looking for a solution...` with a cancel button. This prevents the second run of `my_command.exe`.

How can i avoid this and make my script go to next execution ?

Comment: Try one of the solutions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18898860/116198).

Comment: @ChrisR.Timmons Thanks that worked.